# Save input and give output in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I have data input boxes that gives an output automatically in a box beside.
How can I make it to only display it when i click the button save and not automatically?

Here's the input

```
input#head(type="text" name="head" required="" minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" placeholder="cm" v-model="height")
```

It outputs here automatically whenever I input anything. I want it to display it only when I click save  button.

```
.two
        p Height:
        p.number {{ height }} cm
```

```
a.button(@click="addItems") Save
```

```
export default {
  name: "Measurements",
  data: () => {
    return {
      height: null,
      neck: null,
      biceps: null,
      hips: null,
      quad: null,
      chest: null,
      waist: null,
      calve: null,
      boneweight: null,
      bodyweight: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
      addItems() {
    this.height = this.newHeight;
    this.newHeight = null;
  }
  }
};
```

Comment: Not enough code here to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to duplicate your object, one containing the current state the other one the new state. When pushing the button, you update the current state.

```
export default {
  name: "Measurements",
  created() {
    this.newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.currentState));
  },
  data () {
    return {
      currentState: { },
      newState: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItems() {
      this.currentState= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.newState));
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I press the save button

Comment: You have to implement the details yourself, this is just the way how to approach your problem, make sure the input values are working with the newState and display everthing with the currentState object

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new variable to determine the visible/hidden state of your input. You can do so by adding a `v-if` to your html element and adjusting your `addItems` method just like that.

```
  data: () => {
    return {
       ...
       showHeight: false,
       ...
    };
  },
  methods: {
      addItems() {
        this.showHeight = true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: From this it displays as "True cm"

Comment: You have to put a `v-if` or `v-show` on your html element (in your case in your p element).